# Getting different results from 2 different computer when running the same code like Convert.ToDecimal(prm.Degeri).ToString()

Tags: c#

When I run the code shown below, I get two different results from 2 different computers.

What might be the reason for this?

```
Details;
Computer-1
decimal value1=Convert.ToDecimal(prm.Degeri);  //value1=6;
string svalue1=value1.ToString();              //svalue1="6";

Computer-2
decimal value1=Convert.ToDecimal(prm.Degeri);  //value1=6;
string svalue1=value1.ToString();              //svalue1="6,0";
```

Region and language settings are all the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the `prm.Degeri` values on the two computers?

Comment: I suspect this is because of the `Culture`.

Comment: Double-check under Additional Settings in the Region and Language dialog.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the culture info is the same?  Can you write CultureInfo.CurrentCulture to the debug window and let us know what it says on each machine?

Comment: culture info is: Microsoft .NET CultureInfo “Turkish (Turkey)” (tr-TR) and i recognised that i have this problem when i have a serialized data in the session. when i don't have any serialized data in the session, then i don't have any problem. serialized data and this prm.Degeri value are not connected.

Comment: prm.Degeri is a decimal value like 6

Comment: When I use "Serialization.JsonSerializeObject" to serialize the object, I have this problem. I changed it to "Serialization.SerializeObject" and problem is gone. Weird but it works. I'm sharing this solution here so hopefully this might be maybe helpful for the other people. Thank you all for sharing your time.

Comment: @NurhakKaya You should post that as an 'answer' then instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was because of serilization method. When I use "Serialization.JsonSerializeObject" to serialize the object, I have this problem. I changed it to "Serialization.SerializeObject" and problem is gone. Weird but it works. I'm sharing this solution here so hopefully this might be maybe helpful for the other people. Thank you all for spending your time.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this is that `prm.Degeri` is `"6"` on Computer-1 and `"6,0"` on `Computer-2`. [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), stores the number of significant digits (unlike `double` and `float`, which have a fixed number of significant bits), which it uses when it outputs with `ToString()`.

Comment: It looks like it was because of serilization method. When I use "Serialization.JsonSerializeObject" to serialize the object, I have this problem. I changed it to "Serialization.SerializeObject" and problem is gone. Weird but it works. I'm sharing this solution here so hopefully this might be maybe helpful for the other people. Thank you all for spending your time.